# Apache2 serves gibberish after 2.4 upgrade

Tags: linux, ubuntu, apache-2.4

#### Problem:

Apache 2.4 on Ubuntu Linux 13.10 serves gibberish instead of content over https: using AuthBasic and .htpasswd-based authentication.

Here's an example:

> ‹Å»<:þãÕåød|~>¾…‹ÑõáéÙ§ã=œƒb*¢on¹˜Ë”xôµkl³J­"*g”ª=K­R:ÜCþ¸ž”ÛÓ”8O1sª\ýŠ£!†kØÿâõ”û+=a|@>òÙÂb>àä)N™°$Ùz ‹)1HNÖ­ˆ)¬în‘d£¯YZ3ÊÂ™Åµˆ§¨×Z(;â]ËGKÚB- øœÙ¥ÕK5ï‘K>MU&cêÍHÂ¼L>¡ÙnåÛ­Zr~âï êç¢YÎ9IÓÜÔ0àO¤SCí†GQ«‹¨ÅŸƒ>s(xŸ…L‘ˆ{”$z-¾àiD•¬¥éóçÐrÒ›ñˆ'ä<Œt@pèç´éDlºñT­mî«Y6ÕÓÃŒEÉÜ)›‚C ¾„Øàú,ŸºA¿E)õˆ×êwû}Ò´ÚAç`Ð4[Ôëí Ez`€Á)‘®™ÜÝz®°Â·‚,‡Jd´LåK–K$IÈN6e «ŒÊ¸³Â•ûÙ„.ÅÃ0ÒŒÝt¿W,Æ(ùmÕàÚró7ø ˜>˜„Pé„‚ó:"æ;Ú†X<Û¡¹8“ÌÛÒ¥zÏ¥_ø×Æ„E[¤vX¾±Ž*Å:§4-—ª/Ø‚nGðf _@Øf‰hâ?±Þ]'aÃ»;Ð¨RÝú’  õÎI¿ð-Ñ0 Ø<‘øÚ?ÃéòGË+ÖYgºk[3ªàó§üA¯w¹ÜìÕ/Ô.¸’hÆ!;ùnòÌ¿‰"¤DÍ¨€ä|ªDðU¯­ÅÍè°š%ëî•ƒ9„Ûì

Instead of my ssl-enabled page served over https, which worked on apache 2.2.

A refresh fixes it, displaying the correct content.

#### Things I've done:

- Updated all the Allow and Require tags in the site configuration files.
- Enabled the mods I need (ssl, php5)
- Reviewed the relevant [documentation](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/upgrading.html), which helped me migrate successfuly (until this issue).

#### Note:

- Other (not-authenticated https, or plain http) work fine, serving correct content immediately.
- Error log shows nothing out of the usual

Please let me know what other information I can provide to help diagnose the problem.

Comment: Looks like gzipped content.

Comment: I had previously enabled compression of images and such. These rules were overwritten by the new apache install. Maybe they are still being compressed somehow?